# Why do window.innerWidth and window.devicePixelRatio differ between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

After updating chrome version (to 102)., the fonts on my web page are very small.
In firefox they show up ok.
(If I enable "Toggle Device Toolbar" in Chrome, to emulate e.g. a mobile device, the font sizes are reasonable).

The reported window.innerWidth is completely different when displaying the page
in fireforx and chrome.

In Firefox:

```
window.innerWidth: 769
window.innerHeight: 968
window.devicePixelRatio 1.0
```

In Chrome:

```
window.innerWidth: 7204
window.innerHeight: 1780
window.devicePixelRatio 0.25
```

In Chrome for emulating a mobile device:

```
window.innerWidth: 349
window.innerHeight: 716
window.devicePixelRatio 2
```

How come the values differ so much?
Specifically, why does window.devicePixelRatio differ?
I'm running the browsers on the same hardware. The Screen size is:

```
width: 1920
height: 1080
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have zoomed screen or in settings you have smaller font size, did you check it?

Comment: What is the way to check that? Is this something that is set in the browser? The webapp itself doesn't differ between Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: **Settings** > **Appearance** > **Font size** *or* **Customize fonts** > **Font size** *or* **Mínimum font size**

Answer (score 1):

The source of the problem was, as commented by @NNL993, that the page was zoomed out in Chrome, which I was not aware of.
I also tried several actions that did not make an impact:

- I closed restarted the page (including "empty cache and hard reload"),
- I opened the page in Incognito (I incorrectly thought that this implies completely resetting the web page).
- I tried to zoom-in / zoom-out via the keyboard (pressing Ctrl+ / Ctrl- but I was focused on the debugger, so the content of the debugger zoomed-in/out but not the actual web-page.

It turns out that this feature in Chrome is unrelated to the web-page code layout (the browser retains a map of the zoom level to the web link ?).
So even when rendering in a new tab or even in incognito mode, the zoom was retained.
I then noticed the small icon in the top right corner of the page (see the snapshot).

**The solution was to [reset the zoom](https://www.bemidjistate.edu/offices/its/knowledge-base/adjusting-zoom-settings-in-chrome-browser/)**

[image: snapshot1 - zoom icon for the web page]